# Using regular expression to match words in the same column

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I wonder if this is possible using a regular expression in C#:

I'd like to match the words "FOO" and "BAR" in a multi-line text, but only if those two words start in the same column on consecutive lines.

In other words, this should match, because both words start at the same column:

```
dha skj dh FOO dd fsdf sdf \n
xdsjk fh f BAR 98kf hkjdsf \n
```

This should also match, even though there's also a "BAR" at the wrong place:

```
dha sk jdh FOO dd fsd fs df \n
xd BAR fhf BAR 98 kfhk jdsf \n
```

This should *not* match, because the words start on different columns:

```
dhas kjdh FOO dd fsdfsd ddef \n
xdB2e ARfhf BAR 98kfh kj dsf \n
```

**EDIT**

I managed to get matches in case of equal prefixes for both words using a back reference like this:

```
var pattern = @"(?m)^(.*?)(FOO).*$\n^\1(BAR)" ;
var result = Regex.Match( "xxxFOOyyyy\nxxxBARzzz", pattern ) ;
```

But what I really want is to back-reference to the *length* of the first capturing group.

Comment: Thanks. I added a sample pattern which gives correct results in a small subset of situations

Comment: Ok, good, I see, but now there is another question: what is the final result here? Do you just need True/False result for any given input? Does it have to be a single regex or is a code based solution also "acceptable"?

Comment: I need the match that is returned from Regex.Match() (because "FOO" and "BAR" are only placeholders here), and I'd much prefer a single regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^(?<o>.)*?(FOO).*\n(?<-o>.)*?(BAR)(?(o)(?!))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%28%3f%3co%3e.%29*%3f%28FOO%29.*%5cn%28%3f%3c-o%3e.%29*%3f%28BAR%29%28%3f%28o%29%28%3f!%29%29&i=dha+skj+dh+FOO+dd+fsdf+sdf%0d%0axdsjk+fh+f+BAR+98kf+hkjdsf%0d%0a%0d%0adha+sk+jdh+FOO+dd+fsd+fs+df%0d%0axd+BAR+fhf+BAR+98+kfhk+jdsf%0d%0a%0d%0axxxFOOyyyy%0d%0axxyBARzzz%0d%0a%0d%0adhas+kjdh+FOO+dd+fsdfsd+ddef%0d%0axdB2e+ARfhf+BAR+98kfh+kj+dsf)

**Details**

- `(?m)` - the inline version of the `RegexOptions.Multiline` modifier that makes `^` match the start of a *line*
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?<o>.)*?` - any char but a newline (LF) that is pushed into Group `o` stack (incrementing it) upon each find
- `(FOO)` - Group 1 that matches `FOO`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\n` - a newline
- `(?<-o>.)*?` - any char but a newline (LF) that is pushed off Group `o` stack (decrementing it) upon each find
- `(BAR)` - Group 2: captures `BAR` substring
- `(?(o)(?!))` - a conditional construct that fails the match if Group `o` is not empty (that is, if the number of chars on the first line before `FOO` is different from the number of chars on the second line before `BAR`).

Comment: Although it [works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%28%3f%3co%3e.%29*%3f%28FOO%29.*%5cn%28%3f%3c-o%3e.%29*%3f%28BAR%29&i=dha+skj+dh+FOO+dd+fsdf+sdf%0d%0axdsjk+fh+f+BAR+98kf+hkjdsf%0d%0a%0d%0adha+sk+jdh+FOO+dd+fsd+fs+df%0d%0axd+BAR+fhf+BAR+98+kfhk+jdsf%0d%0a%0d%0adhas+kjdh+FOO+dd+fsdfsd+ddef%0d%0axdB2e+ARfhf+BAR+98kfh+kj+dsf) without `(?(o)(?!))`, I prefer to keep things explicit with these kinds of patterns.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton! I never heard of this "stacking" construct before.

Comment: @miasbeck See [Matching Nested Constructs with Balancing Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html) and [Balancing Group Definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing-group-definitions) for more details.

Comment: Some food for thought for sure for me :)